# Difference between these Two syntaxes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm not an expert in React Js and want to know the difference between these two syntaxes in the ES6 syntax.

```
const items = array.map(thing => <p key={thing}>{thing}</p>)
function addItem(){
    setArray(previtems  => { return [...previtems, `Thing ${array.length + 1}`]});
  }
```

and

```
const items = array.map(thing => <p key={thing}>{thing}</p>)
function addItem(){
    setArray([...items, `Thing ${array.length + 1}`]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one is [functional `setState`](https://www.google.com/search?q=functional+setstate&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN1027IN1027&oq=functional+setstate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l3j69i60l2.3854j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It gives guarantee that the value of `prevItems` will be the most updated one. This pattern is to be used whenever next state depends on the previous state.